# C: sbrk() addresses ascending or descending?

Tags: c, unix, memory-management, heap-memory, sbrk

When sbrk() returns a pointer to an address that is the beginning of the heap, are the addresses ascending or descending? For example, if I had a 10 byte heap from addresses 1 to 10, would sbrk() return a pointer to address 10 or 1?

On a similar note, heap addresses tend to grow "down"... but how can I figure out whether the addresses increase or decrease on my computer?

Comment: What about calling sbrk() twice and testing whether the addresses increase or decrease?

Answer (score 2):

The man page on Mac OS X says:

> The `brk` and `sbrk` functions are historical curiosities left over from earlier days before the
>        advent of virtual memory management.
>
> The current value of the program break is reliably returned by `sbrk(0)`.
>
> The `sbrk` function returns a pointer to the base of the
>        new storage if successful; otherwise -1 with `errno` set to indicate why the allocation failed.

Suppose you use:

```
void *base = sbrk(1024);
```

After that, assuming no error, `base` will contain the starting address of a 1024 byte (minimum) block of memory; `(char *)base + 1024` will be beyond what you requested, though it may still be valid since the page size may be larger than 1024.

It doesn't say directly whether a subsequent allocation will have a larger or smaller address than another.  However, it is likely to be in increasing order of addresses.

> The `brk()` function sets the break or lowest address of a
>        process's data segment (uninitialized data) to addr (immediately above bss).  Data addressing
>        is restricted between `addr` and the lowest stack pointer to the stack segment.  Memory is allocated by `brk` in page size pieces; if `addr` is not evenly divisible by the system page size, it
>        is increased to the next page boundary.

This implies that the extra space is after the data and bss segments, and grows up towards the stack (which grows downwards in memory).  However, relying on that would probably be foolhardy.  You'd do best to use `sbrk(0)` to establish the current end after calling `sbrk(extra)` to get extra space; this will tell you what you really got and the two addresses tell you where it was made available.

Comment: To me the part about `historical curiosities` is a huge imbecility laid by an Apple "I feel superior" employee, who maybe thought that they are actually working and having new ways to do stuff, whereas Unix world was frozen and just another old jeezer in comparison. However, he just made a fool of himself instead and now the history is the remnant of this phrase in Apple's manual, which only serves his (and apple) discredit because of unjustified arrogance. Now I'd like to see the explanation of that phrase.

Comment: later note: it seems this phrase actually comes from BSD original manual. so the rash belongs to some BSD "i feel superior" guy, and not to Apple. The Apple guy only deformed the phrase to make it even more arrogant, lol.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux, you can examine `/proc/$PID/maps` to see how the virtual address space is utilized for each process.

Sample code: mappingTest.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int foo(int depth) {
    char buf[8192];
    if (0 == depth)
        printf("%p\n", buf);
    if (1000 < depth) {
        printf("%p\n", buf);
        return getchar();
    } else {
        return 1 + foo(depth + 1);
    }
}

int main() {
    const size_t SIZE = 1000 * 1000 * 1000;
    getchar();
    char * const p = malloc(SIZE);
    printf("%p\n", p);
    getchar();
    free(p);
    getchar();
    foo(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Note: `char buf[8192]` and recursion of `1000` times assume that the maximum stack size is 8 MB (you can confirm with `ulimit -s`.)

```
$ gcc mappingTest.c -o mappingTest -Wall -Wextra -Wno-missing-field-initializers -std=c89 -O0 -g3 && echo OK
OK
$ ./mappingTest
```

At the 1st `getchar()`, we see the following memory mappings for the process:

```
$ cat /proc/`pidof mappingTest`/maps
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 21687266                           /home/nodakai/prog/exp/mappingTest
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 08:05 21687266                           /home/nodakai/prog/exp/mappingTest
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:05 21687266                           /home/nodakai/prog/exp/mappingTest
7f2e96e8a000-7f2e9703f000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 14314431                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f2e9703f000-7f2e9723f000 ---p 001b5000 08:05 14314431                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f2e9723f000-7f2e97243000 r--p 001b5000 08:05 14314431                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f2e97243000-7f2e97245000 rw-p 001b9000 08:05 14314431                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f2e97245000-7f2e9724a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f2e9724a000-7f2e9726c000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 14314443                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7f2e97443000-7f2e97446000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f2e97469000-7f2e9746c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f2e9746c000-7f2e9746d000 r--p 00022000 08:05 14314443                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7f2e9746d000-7f2e9746f000 rw-p 00023000 08:05 14314443                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7fffa6d43000-7fffa6d64000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fffa6dff000-7fffa6e00000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

We hit Enter and proceed to the 2nd `getchar()`.

I got `0x7f2e5b4dd010` on my terminal as the value of `p` and it falls within the first anonymous mapping region `7f2e5b4dd000-7f2e96e8a000` in the below listing, but it didin't exist in the above listing.

```
$ cat /proc/`pidof mappingTest`/maps
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 21687266                           /home/nodakai/prog/exp/mappingTest
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 08:05 21687266                           /home/nodakai/prog/exp/mappingTest
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:05 21687266                           /home/nodakai/prog/exp/mappingTest
7f2e5b4dd000-7f2e96e8a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f2e96e8a000-7f2e9703f000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 14314431                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f2e9703f000-7f2e9723f000 ---p 001b5000 08:05 14314431                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f2e9723f000-7f2e97243000 r--p 001b5000 08:05 14314431                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f2e97243000-7f2e97245000 rw-p 001b9000 08:05 14314431                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f2e97245000-7f2e9724a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f2e9724a000-7f2e9726c000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 14314443                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7f2e97443000-7f2e97446000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f2e97468000-7f2e9746c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f2e9746c000-7f2e9746d000 r--p 00022000 08:05 14314443                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7f2e9746d000-7f2e9746f000 rw-p 00023000 08:05 14314443                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7fffa6d43000-7fffa6d64000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fffa6dff000-7fffa6e00000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

We hit Enter and proceed to the 3rd `getchar()`.

In the below listing, we see the anonymous mapping region disappeared due to `free()`.

```
$ cat /proc/`pidof mappingTest`/maps
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 21687266                           /home/nodakai/prog/exp/mappingTest
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 08:05 21687266                           /home/nodakai/prog/exp/mappingTest
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:05 21687266                           /home/nodakai/prog/exp/mappingTest
7f2e96e8a000-7f2e9703f000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 14314431                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f2e9703f000-7f2e9723f000 ---p 001b5000 08:05 14314431                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f2e9723f000-7f2e97243000 r--p 001b5000 08:05 14314431                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f2e97243000-7f2e97245000 rw-p 001b9000 08:05 14314431                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f2e97245000-7f2e9724a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f2e9724a000-7f2e9726c000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 14314443                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7f2e97443000-7f2e97446000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f2e97468000-7f2e9746c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f2e9746c000-7f2e9746d000 r--p 00022000 08:05 14314443                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7f2e9746d000-7f2e9746f000 rw-p 00023000 08:05 14314443                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7fffa6d43000-7fffa6d64000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fffa6dff000-7fffa6e00000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

We hit Enter and proceed to the 4th `getchar()` in the deeply nested calls of `foo()`.

I got `0x7fffa6d60ba0` and `0x7fffa6582ff0` on my terminal as the addresses of `buf` in the 1st and 1001st recursive call of `foo()`.  Both of them fall within the `[stack]` region (`7fffa6582000-7fffa6d64000`; 0x7e2000 == 8 MB) now.  But note that it was previously `7fffa6d43000-7fffa6d64000`; 0x21000 == 132 KB.

```
$ cat /proc/`pidof mappingTest`/maps
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 21687266                           /home/nodakai/prog/exp/mappingTest
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 08:05 21687266                           /home/nodakai/prog/exp/mappingTest
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:05 21687266                           /home/nodakai/prog/exp/mappingTest
7f2e96e8a000-7f2e9703f000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 14314431                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f2e9703f000-7f2e9723f000 ---p 001b5000 08:05 14314431                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f2e9723f000-7f2e97243000 r--p 001b5000 08:05 14314431                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f2e97243000-7f2e97245000 rw-p 001b9000 08:05 14314431                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f2e97245000-7f2e9724a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f2e9724a000-7f2e9726c000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 14314443                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7f2e97443000-7f2e97446000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f2e97468000-7f2e9746c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f2e9746c000-7f2e9746d000 r--p 00022000 08:05 14314443                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7f2e9746d000-7f2e9746f000 rw-p 00023000 08:05 14314443                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7fffa6582000-7fffa6d64000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fffa6dff000-7fffa6e00000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

You may have more fun with inline assembly like this:

```
#define PEEK_ESP(reg)          \
   __asm__ __volatile__ (      \
       "movq %%rsp, %0"        \
       : "=r"(reg)             \
   )
...
void *p;
PEEK_ESP(p);
```